# Clear textarea after enter key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to clear the textarea content after enter key press on react. However when enter key press the text area clears but the enter key remains (new line). How can I fix this?

```
constructor(){
    this.state = { text : '' }
}

keypress(e){ 
   if(e.key == 'Enter'){
      this.setState({
        send_message: ''
      })
   }
}

<textarea value={this.state.text} placeholder="Text" rows="1" className="form-textarea typing-area" onKeyPress={this.keypress.bind(this)}></textarea>
```

Comment: try to add `return false;` at the end of your keypress function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `event.preventDefault` when the key is 'Enter':

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text : '' }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.keypress = this.keypress.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({text: event.target.value});
  }
  
  keypress(e){ 
    if(e.key === 'Enter'){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        send_message: this.state.text,
        text: '',
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea 
          value={this.state.text} 
          placeholder="Text" 
          rows="1" 
          className="form-textarea typing-area" 
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyPress={this.keypress} 
        />
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this text area is for your users to leave comments. I would place my text area inside a form element and `onSubmit` with a `handleSubmit` function you would define above your render:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ comment: event.target.value });
  };
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ comment: '' });
  };
render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h4>Add a Comment</h4>
        <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.comment} />
        <div>
          <button>Submit Comment</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Notice in `handleSubmit` I added the `e.preventDefault()` since it is a form element and the default behavior of HTML form elements is to submit. Then I added a `this.setState()` with an object with a comment property and a value of empty string so that your text area can empty out. In your case, you can call it `{ text:  '' }`.

Notice I also have an `onChange` event handler with `{this.handleChange}`. `handleChange` receives this `event` object and the new value of your `text` state or in my case `comment` state will come from  `event.target.value`.

As you are developing this component I would also be testing it out along the way. So consider a test that finds the textarea element, simulates a change event, provide a fake event object, force the component to update and then assert that the text area has indeed changed its value. In such a test you would need to manually set the `event.target.value` value.